# Difference between two Sine wave equations

Tags: matlab

I'm confused as what is the difference between these two sine wave equations

```
x(t) = Sin(2*pi*F*t)
```

and

```
x(t) = Sin(2*pi*F*nTs)
```

`x(t) = Sin(2*pi*F*t)` is supposed to be used with analog signal, here `t` is supposed to me the samples when speaking of matlab.

```
A = 4;       %Amplitude
Freq = 100;
Time = 1/Freq; %0.01
Fs = 1000;      %Sampling Frequency 
Ts = 1/Fs;   %Sampling Rate 
t = 0:Ts:(Time); 
x=A*sin(2*pi*Freq*t);
```

The output,

[image]

Similarly if I use the stem command than a plot command I will get the sampled values instead.

[image]

If I'm getting the sampled result from the first equation than what is the purpose to replace `t` by `nTs` in the equation and using the second equation ?

I couldn't be able to demonstrate the difference and visualize it in Matlab. Kindly guide me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first equation:

```
x(t) = Sin(2*pi*F*t)
```

is for a *continuous* ("analogue") signal, where `t` may take any real value.

The second equation:

```
x(t) = Sin(2*pi*F*n*Ts)
```

(I assume that this is the correct version - it looks like you have a typo in the question ?)

is for a *discrete* ("sampled" or "digital") signal, where `n` is the sample number (integer) and `Ts` is the sample interval (inverse of sample rate). It has values only at the discrete sampling points where `t = n * Ts`.

In your MATLAB code you are effectively sampling a continuous function, so although you start off with the first (continuous) equation you end up with the second equation because you are only evaluating (sampling) the continuous function at a set of discrete points.

Note also that as `Ts -> 0` the discrete version tends towards the continuous version.